# What is the maximum size of the variable pointed by pointer which can be passed in a c function?

Tags: c, pointers, stack

Is there a limit to the size of the variable(structure) which can be passed via pointer to a function.Also how big in size a variable can be defined(structure within the structure and so on ...and having arrays of sizes varying from 100-500)
for a safe running of the programme.(no stack overflow, memory propblem ,pointer corruption)
This is with reference to the embedded system having memories limited to 64K to 512K

Comment: How can this possibly be answered by somebody else? You have to check the capacity of your system and configuration.

Comment: A pointer is a memory address, and in itself fixed size (like 16 or 32 or 64 bit). It does not depend on the size of the data it points to (if that is even a meaningful thing, what is the size of a circular list for example?).

Comment: If your code needs to run on a system with 64 KiB memory, you'd best keep your variable smaller than 64 KiB.  Or if it is on a 512 KiB system, then less than 512 KiB.  It's roughly like answering "how long is a piece of string".

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have three questions:

- How large a block of memory can be pointed to with a pointer: The limit here is the limit of the pointer size - be it a 32 bit or 64 bit pointer. But in practice no machine are likely to have enough memory to make the 64 bit restriction an issue.
- How large a structure can I declare on the stack (this means a local declaration at some level): the stack size is limited on all hardware, usually much more restricted than the heap, the stack is not intended for large objects and the stack limits can be restrictive especially in embedded systems. The issue here is not the size of the single stack object but more the total size of the stack that is restricted.
- How large a structure can I allocate from the heap (this means structures allocated with `new` or `malloc`: The heap is the 'rest' of available memory; this area is generally larger and the better place for large allocations; again the maximum space is completely dependent on the execution environment. There is a maximum amount of continuous heap available at any time for the process which amount s to the largest object that can be allocated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the C language is concerned, the largest size of a structure is

`2 ^ (8*sizeof(size_t))` bytes,

where `^` should be read as "power of".

Beyond that, the limits depend on your specific system.